# Update with DOM children and data propagation

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to update the DOM containing children with data propagation.

The first time when DOM is populated, the data is properly propagated to their children.
However when I update the parent DOM with new data, the children DOM doesn't update along with it.

Also surprisingly, the old data were retrievable from the children elements, which I am strongly against because the data is too huge and I don't want to have old/extra data persist, which holds the reference and retains the old data. (Memory leak in my sense)

```js
const DATA = [{
  name: "data1",
  left: 70,
  top: 70,
  radius: 20
}, {
  name: "data2",
  left: 200,
  top: 100,
  radius: 50
}];
const svg = d3.select("#svg");

// Not working as expected
function loadData(data) {
  console.log(data);
  const container = svg.selectAll(".container")
    .data(data);
  container.exit().remove();
  const enter = container.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "container");
  enter.append("circle");
  enter.append("text");

  container.merge(enter)
    .attr("transform", entry => `translate(0,${entry.top})`)
  svg.selectAll(".container circle")
    .attr("r", entry => entry.radius)
    .attr("cx", entry => entry.left);
  svg.selectAll(".container text")
    .text(entry => entry.name);
}

// Working, but not desired
function expected(data) {
  console.log(data);
  const container = svg.selectAll(".container")
    .data(data);
  container.exit().remove();
  const enter = container.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "container");
  enter.append("circle");
  enter.append("text");
  
  container.merge(enter)
    .attr("transform", entry => `translate(0,${entry.top})`)
  svg.selectAll(".container circle")
    .data(data)
    .attr("r", entry => entry.radius)
    .attr("cx", entry => entry.left);
  svg.selectAll(".container text")
    .data(data)
    .text(entry => entry.name);
}
let i = 0;
loadData(DATA);

function updateData() {
  i = (i+1) % 2;
  loadData(DATA.slice(i,i+1));
}
function expectedUpdate() {
  i = (i+1) % 2;
  expected(DATA.slice(i,i+1));
}
```

```css
button {
  display: inline-block;
}
svg {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="updateData();">Update</button>
<button onclick="expectedUpdate();">Expected</button>
<svg id="svg"></svg>
```

This is just demonstration, where I have a parent `<g>` element, and 2 children `<circle>` & `<text>` are appending to it.

The first time when it renders, I used the `loadData()` method to populate the DOM, the corresponding children DOMs (circle & text) were able to retrieve the data inserted into their parent DOM (g), which showed a proper data propagation along the DOM tree.

However when I press "update" button multiple times, only the parent DOM is updating, and children DOMs are able access the non-existing data (old data).

The "expected" button shows what is the expected behaviour, but I can see the data is being binded multiple times, which I as a javascript engineer am so afraid of this kind of data binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem in your *non-working* function (`loadData`) is that you're using `selectAll`. Unlike `select`, `selectAll` **doesn't** propagate the data.

Have a look at this table I made summarising the differences between them:

| Method | select() | selectAll() |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Selection | selects the first element that matches the selector string | selects all elements that match the selector string |
| Grouping | Does not affect grouping | Affects grouping |
| Data propagation | Propagates data | Doesn't propagate data |

As you can see, the main information for you is this:

- `select`: **propagates** the data.
- `selectAll`: **doesn't propagate** the data.

Given that your snippet has just **one** child (circle and text) per group, the simplest solution is just changing `selectAll` to `select`. However, if you have more than one child per parent, the best (and idiomatic) solution is creating a nested enter-update-exit selection, which is a bit more laborious.

Besides that, you're missing the key function:

```
const container = svg.selectAll(".container")
    .data(data, function(d) {
        return d.name;
    });
```

Here is your code with those changes:

```js
const DATA = [{
  name: "data1",
  left: 70,
  top: 70,
  radius: 20
}, {
  name: "data2",
  left: 200,
  top: 100,
  radius: 50
}];
const svg = d3.select("#svg");

// Not working as expected
function loadData(data) {
  console.log(data);
  const container = svg.selectAll(".container")
    .data(data, function(d) {
      return d.name;
    });
  container.exit().remove();
  const enter = container.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "container");
  enter.append("circle");
  enter.append("text");

  container.merge(enter)
    .attr("transform", entry => `translate(0,${entry.top})`)
  svg.select(".container circle")
    .attr("r", entry => entry.radius)
    .attr("cx", entry => entry.left);
  svg.select(".container text")
    .text(entry => entry.name);
}

// Working, but not desired
function expected(data) {
  console.log(data);
  const container = svg.selectAll(".container")
    .data(data);
  container.exit().remove();
  const enter = container.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "container");
  enter.append("circle");
  enter.append("text");

  container.merge(enter)
    .attr("transform", entry => `translate(0,${entry.top})`)
  svg.selectAll(".container circle")
    .data(data)
    .attr("r", entry => entry.radius)
    .attr("cx", entry => entry.left);
  svg.selectAll(".container text")
    .data(data)
    .text(entry => entry.name);
}
let i = 0;
loadData(DATA);

function updateData() {
  i = (i + 1) % 2;
  loadData(DATA.slice(i, i + 1));
}

function expectedUpdate() {
  i = (i + 1) % 2;
  expected(DATA.slice(i, i + 1));
}
```

```css
button {
  display: inline-block;
}

svg {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="updateData();">Update</button>
<button onclick="expectedUpdate();">Expected</button>
<svg id="svg"></svg>
```

Comment: Hi Gerardo, thank you for answering the question! Very appreciated!
I somehow managed to get my real model solved, but completely don't understand what is going on. I see the key function being a big factor in this example, however, when I want to add transition animation, I could see the whole graph being redrawn rather than update. I would like to know how the key function works if you don't mind, thank you!!

Comment: @ShiraishiMai This is a good explanation about the key function: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/